# Parsable output from javac? XML?

Tags: java, ant, jenkins, javac

We currently build our java app using ant.
My goal is to find a way to identify which file caused the build to fail.

What I *could* do-

- Parse for everything that has ".java" in it.
- Filter out everything that has ".java:number: warning"
- Parse that line for the file, line, and reason.

This isn't that hard... but it seems a bit non-robust. (A better word currently escapes me. maybe "bad")

Too bad there isn't anyway to have it output in XML? Or maybe there is?

EDIT: One of the assumptions of this project were that we wouldn't want to do builds on every change, but now that I've worked with jenkins a bit, I am thinking that this might actually be possible.

Comment: cant you just read from System.err? then you only get the error messages, which are quick to evaluate..

Comment: Yes, I can, but I still need to filter for the files only and filter out warnings.. which is what the steps I listed do.

Comment: Have look at [javax.tools](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html), but I don't know if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is. Probably one of the reasons Eclipse has its own compiler.

You can limit the problem by having your own ant task (so you have more control about output formatting and won't have to parse the whole ant output).

If you are designing a build system pulling the sources out of a source control (you tagged jenkins), an easier option is to list the changes between the last successful build and the broken ones.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The end goal is to identify "who broke the build". However, we will be doing daily builds and the files that change daily are far too numerous.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I wonder if it would be possible to do 30 minutes builds. Will have to ponder this.

Comment: @user606723: we have jenkins build on every push. Jenkins doesn't fall behind because it always just pulls the latest. So sometimes it gets a few people's commits in one build (because the previous build took too long and multiple pushes occurred in the interim), but it's still manageable as far as "who broke the build" goes.

Comment: I am not sure out structure supports "every push", but I am going to look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Way to have output as XML is:

```
ant -listener org.apache.tools.ant.XmlLogger
```

Output will be saved log.xml in build directory. Unfortunately structure does not support your needs too well.